# While Performing 2D array representation in memory leads to Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've presented the codes below only while executing the first loop it works fine but as soon as i uncomment the second loop it starts to throw segmentation fault. My code is as below.

```
// Write a program to add two m*n matrices using pointer.

#include <stdio.h>

#define m 2
#define n 2

int main() {
    int (*a)[n];
    int (*b)[n], i, j; //, *(sum)[n], i, j;

    printf("Enter first matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", *(a + i) + j);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter second matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", *(b + i) + j);
        }
    }   

    // printf("The Sum of matrix is:\n");
    // for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    //     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    //         // *(*(sum + i) + j) = *(*(a + i) + j) + *(*(b + i) + j);
    //         // printf("\t%d", *(*(sum + i) + j));
    //     }
    //     printf("\n");
    // }
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are uninitialized pointers. They need to be initialized correctly, e.g. with `malloc`. Side note: although `*(*(a+i)+j)` *should* work, it would be easier to understand if written as `a[i][j]`.

Comment: `int (*a)[n];` - this declares a pointer to an array of n elements. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @user3386109 yeah declaring array variable as `a[i][j]` works fine but isn't that `int (*a)[n]` does the same thing like `a[i][j]` in case of 2D array pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA yes of course isn't that `int (*a)[5]` same as declaring `int [2][5]` ??

Comment: @ashim888, no it is not.

Comment: I wasn't saying to declare the variables as `a[m][n]`. It's perfectly fine to declare the variables as `int (*a)[n]` and use them as `a[i][j]`. The only problem is that the declaration `int (*a)[n]` creates a pointer, but that pointer doesn't point to anything. You need to allocate memory for the array. Try `int (*a)[n] = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));`, and same for `b`.

Comment: @user3386109 Worked perfectly!! So a variable can not be used to define a size on an array. to use any pointer variable to represent an array requires some kind of initial memory assignment before processing. thats what malloc did. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining `a` and `b` as 2D arrays, but as uninitialized pointers to 2D arrays. passing addresses into these invokes undefined behavior.  You must make these pointers point to an actual array, either static, automatic or allocated from the heap.

You can define 2D arrays this way:

```
    int a[m][n], b[m][n];
```

If you are required to use pointers, you can allocate the 2D arrays with `malloc`:

```
    int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * m);
    int (*b)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*b) * m);
```

In your program, it is more readable to use the `[]` syntax, even for pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define m 2
#define n 2

int main(void) {
    int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * m);
    int (*b)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*b) * m);
    int (*sum)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*sum) * m);

    printf("Enter first matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter second matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }   

    printf("The Sum of matrices is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            printf("\t%d", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: dude i got that from user3386109 anyways thanks though!!! guess you need to correct again adding this line at the top #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @ashim888 Comments are a quick and dirty way to help you out, since I didn't have time to write up a full answer. Now that chqrlie has written this answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark. Thanks.

Comment: @ashim888: Thank you.  Note that his proposition `int (*a)[n] = malloc(m*n*sizeof(int));` is somewhat error prone, if `m` and `n` are large, `m*n` may overflow before being converted to potentially larger type `size_t` for the final multiplication.  For example, allocating a 2000x2000 matrix with this expression will fail on x86 platforms. `whatever_type *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * number_of_elements)` can be used for any type and size to allocate an array of `number_of_elements`.

Comment: @chqrlie something i will remember forever. much appreciated!!! thanks guys for quick response.